# Слайдер Slick левая стрелка не переключает слайды

Tags: слайдер, slick.js

Ссылка на слайдер - https://kruto.kz/slider/

Решил поменять расположение стрелок слайдера, CSS код для редактирования внешнего вида слайдера я вынес в файл index.html, далее в классе ".slick-prev" я поменял значение left:-25px; на left:150px;, после чего левая стрелка передвинулась как мне нужно, но перестала функционировать. Интересно что если тоже самое сделать с правой стрелкой, а именно в классе ".slick-next" поменять right: -25px; на right: 150px; то стрелка тоже встает как мне нужно и работает. В чем проблема, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Очевидно что ваш слайдер работает, дело в стилях. Ведь при наведении на правую кнопку курскор изменяется (cursor:pointer) а на левую нет (хотя для левой кнопки тоже cursor:pointer). Тоесть левая кнопка оказывается под каким то слоем. Как вариант повысьте z-index (до 1000) и заработает, но лучше полностью разобраться в стилях и почему левая кнопка недоступна для клика (под каким то прозрачным слоем)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, заработало! Добавил в класс ".slick-prev" z-index:1; и кнопка заработала. Не стал заливать на хостинг, по этому по ссылке старый вариант, не рабочий.